VSCode Pylance highlighting not showing when there is too many files
This is current setting.JSON
{
    "remote.autoForwardPortsSource": "output",
    "python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "python.analysis.diagnosticMode": "workspace",
    "python.analysis.exclude": [
        "**/data/**",
        "**/tmp/**",
        "**/output/**",
        "**/dataset/**",
        "**/ckpts/**",
        "**/work_dirs/**",
        "**/assets/**",
        "**/docs/**",
        "**/figs/**",
        "**/resources/**",
        "**/.git/**",
        "**/.github/**",
    ],
    "files.watcherExclude": {
        "**/.git/**": true,
        "**/tmp/**": true,
        "**/ouput/**": true,
        "**/others/**": true,
        "**/data/**": true,
        "**/.github/**": true,
    },
    "explorer.autoReveal": false
}

Pylance is wokring well by showing description of library like this:

however, the problem is it is not highlighting the code properly.
The problem is solved if I delete whole project and highlight comes back. But, whenever number of files in project is getting larger, this happens again.
Any help would be greately appreciate!

shoudn't the title be not work

Problem is solved by commenting out
"python.analysis.diagnosticMode": "workspace",

in the setting.JSON.
I am assuming that "diagnosticMode: workspace" makes VScode to look at all of the files in the workspace, which affect pylance highlighting feature.
